# Recording scripts using HTTP Test Script Recording vs Blazemeter plugins

Tags: scripting, jmeter, correlation, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

Just a simple question, which Jmeter recording method is better for the timebeing? Record script using HTTP Test Script Recording (using proxy) or Blazemeter plugins? Can provide justification for each?

Because at first I record with blazemeter plugins, when I tried to apply correlation, it never works. But then I try to record manual using proxy, my correlation works. I tried to correlate userSession in the webtours test application.

Mind if you can share your thoughts on that? In which scenario we have to choose scripting using Blazemeter plugins or proxy in Jmeter apps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Both basically intercept HTTP requests and convert them to JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) requires extra steps like importing certificates, configuring proxy server, etc.
- BlazeMeter Chrome Extension doesn't require any extra setup, however for certain POST requests it may add [multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) where it's not needed

Going forward you can consider the following alternatives:

- [Correlations Recorder Plugin for JMeter](https://github.com/Blazemeter/CorrelationRecorder) - where you can add correlation rules beforehand and they will be automatically applied to the content substituting hard-coded values with the appropriate JMeter Variarbles, you will still have to perform correlation, but it will be one place only
- [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80/) - which is capable of exporting recorded requests in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic parameters (even including timestamps), but it requires Internet connectivity so if you're recording a local application you won't be able to use it.

If you're still interested in my "thoughts" I don't think that any "recording" solution can substitute a human, especially when it comes to more complex topics like simulation of [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) requests so I would recommend using a 3rd-party sniffer tool to compare the network footprint from the real browser with JMeter's and amend JMeter configuration so it would be 100% accuracy.